# When I start running, it won't stop when I let go of shift. Why?

Tags: game-maker

Following is my code, and after I let go of shift the image speed goes back to normal but not the variable I created called `movespeed`. What should I add or change to fix it?

```
//Run with left shift
if (keyboard_check(vk_lshift))
{
     movespeed = 5;
     image_speed = 0.14;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your image won't stop moving is because you need to reset the speed variable, like so:

```
if(keyboard_check_released(vk_lshift))
{
    movespeed = 0;
}
```

Or, you could just put the `movespeed` variable in the bottom of the step event, after all relevant movement code has been calculated.

**EDIT**

One other solution is do something like this:

```
//Run with left shift
if (keyboard_check(vk_lshift))
{
    movespeed = 5;
    image_speed = 0.14;
}
else 
{
    // We only come here if the key is not determined to be down
    movespeed = 0;
    image_speed = 0;
}
```

All 3 options will virtually give the same result.

Comment: the code worked and now it stops constantly running, but now my image speed doesn't change at all, so when it is running the animation doesn't speed up

Comment: @GameboyTheCollector without examination of your code I don't really know what could be causing the issue, perhaps you should update your question with some more relevant code and maybe I can help you :).

Comment: i asked another question, thank you, and how do i close this question

Comment: I wouldn't recommend closing your question just in case someone else has the same issue as you.

Comment: @GameboyTheCollector -  if this answer has resolved your question you should [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - this helps others who may have the same/similar problem. In contrast [closed & on-hold](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) refers to questions that aren't a good fit for our site & need to be either improved or removed - since your question is [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it shouldn't be closed.